# Why does the zero divergence of displacement field mean that a body's volume is conserved?

Tags: continuum-mechanics

Why is the zero divergence of displacement field means that a body's volume is conserved?

I got this question while reading the research paper "ON THE DERIVATION OF ELECTRIC BODY FORCE,COUPLE AND POWER IN AN ELECTROELASTIC BODY" Author: Jiashi Yang

In the paper the author assumes that the infinitesimal displacement field preserves the volume of the electronic continuum (which is a continuum that is massless and having a negative charge density), and after that he writes that the divergence of infinitesimal displacement field is equal to zero.

Comment: Are you asking about the [divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem)? If the divergence of the displacements is zero, there is no source or sink of volume.

Comment: Yes. But how is the divergence of displacement related to change of volume? What is the proof that the divergence of displacement is equal to source or sink of volume

Comment: You can search online for `divergence "displacement field" volume conservation` as well as I can. The first hit I get is [here](http://assets.press.princeton.edu/chapters/s9093.pdf); see specifically the discussion following Eq. (1.22).

Comment: Sorry for my delay. I read the part you mentioned. And it's the right answer. Thank you.

Comment: It mentions that volumetric strain is equal to the divergence of displacement. Thus zero divergence of displacement implies that volume is conserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Volumetric strain is equal to the divergence of displacement. Thus zero divergence of displacement implies that volume is conserved.